# HDMI Stuttering when adding additional run

Tags: audio, video, multiple-monitors, hdmi, hdcp

I am not positive this is the optimal site for this question. please migrate to appropriate place if not.

Originally posted in [r/techsupport](https://redd.it/5vsngr) on reddit

---

### Overview

I have a video feed from our auditorium that I need to send to multiple locations. But I also need to send the Audio feed from the soundboard to the same location. I am having nothing but issues with whatever I try.

### TL;DR

I have multiple components that arn't playing nice with eachother. Im trying to figure out what and how to fix my issues.

### The Pieces & Setup

[image: Setup Diagram]

- ***Projector*** -  [Epson PowerLite 1985WU WUXGA](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=0FC-000M-00049)

  - This is our Primary video display located in our auditorium. This is the Higest priority device.
- ***AV Reciever*** - [Sony STRDH750](http://www.sony.com/electronics/av-receivers/str-dh750)

  - This is our 'video switching' / Speaker Amp in our cafe. Output connected directly to *Cafe TV Monitor*
- ***Café TV Monitor*** - [Sony KDL-40R380B](https://esupport.sony.com/US/p/model-home.pl?mdl=KDL40R380B)
- ***Preview Monitor*** - Misc HDMI Monitor

  - Not mission critical but it would be missed if not in play.
- ***HDMI Inserter*** - [Blackbird HDMI Audio Inserter](https://www.monoprice.com/Product?p_id=13347)

  - Used to *insert* audio feed from our soundboard into the HDMI signal.
  - ~~Appears to work on its own.~~
  - **(EDIT 3-7)** unconvinced this is working flawlessly but unsure how to isolate issue.
- ***HDMI Splitter*** - [Blackbird 4K HDMI 2x4 Matrix](https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=15866)

  - HDMI Splitter with the added ability to allow me to easily add another input.
  - ~~Known Working.~~ New component *belived* to be working as manufacturer suggests
- ***HDMI Pigtails*** - [HDMI Extender Using Cat5e](https://www.monoprice.com/Product?p_id=8121)

  - 2 pair in play
  - these were inexpensive *HDMI pigtails* that appear to work. - might possibly be part of the issue?
  - currently unable to fully isolate some components others without use of these devices.
- ***Video Card*** - [NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-960/specifications)

  - I am unaware of any issues directly with this card.
- ***Presentation Software*** - [Proclaim Church Presentation Software](https://proclaimonline.com/)

  - Our Presentation Software of choice.
  - We haven't had any video issues with *Proclaim* since we upgraded our computer, but im throwing it in here just to be thorough.
- ***CAT5e Shielded Cable*** - `CAT5e Shielded Enhanced 350 MHz F/UTP, Verified to ANSI/TIA-568-C.2 PVC JKT` [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoxqB.jpg)

One Additional building note

We have REALY funky (for lack of a better term) electrical grounding issues with a lot of our audio equipment. I have implemented Power conditioners in most locations I have had issues with.

### The Problem

When I connect everything up as [seen above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC7po.png), I get pictures and audio on all devices. After a short period of time all devices act as if signal is dropped momentarly.

It is my believe that (if at all) signal is only dropped for a fraction of a second, however it is long enough for all devices in this setup to attempt to *reconnect* thus causing a momentary *flash* on the screen and a equally as long moment of silence.

### Troubleshooting Results

Here is what I did to determine what I believe is the cause.

[image: First Attempt]

First I Took the HDMI *Audio Inserter* and moved it directly before the *AV Receiver* to see if the stuttering stopped on all devices or just the TV. The issue was not resolved.

[image: Issue Isolated]

At this point It appears that I have removed the issue. but I still need this device connected.

### My Question

- Has anyone had any similar experience?
- If it is in fact the run, How should I resolve it.

  - [√] Purchase Shielded Cat5e cable? [√ DONE]
  - Use Actual HDMI cable. (I believe this run is around 50'-75' so I am pretty sure I could use an actual HDMI cable.)
  - Purchase a Higher caliber HDMI over Cat5e/6 system? - Suggestions?
  - Something Else?

## **Update** 3/7/17

This week I updated the run to the *AV receiver* with [*CAT5e Shielded Cable*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoxqB.jpg) cable.

I have yet to change the patch cables to shielded ones but I did see a slight improvement during my testing period. But Come Sunday Morning when I need it to work as flawlessly as possible, the video (including the projector) start cutting in and out quite frequently.

### New Observations

- *AV Receiver* run is prone to cut out when bumped even just a little bit. however still cuts out without being bumped as well.
- I think it is safe to say that when I  have (for lack of a better fraise) more complex audio (i.e. a full band in the mixer), the video is more likely to cut out.
- New this week, the *Projector* run started cutting in and out too. (even after I disconnected the *AV Receiver* run from the *HDMI Splitter* which has prevented the issue in weeks prior.)

  - My suspicion is this may be caused by the *Audio Inserter* being that that is the only thing that changed inline on the *Projector* run.
- I am currently not sure why, but all my issues are greatly increased on Sunday during service, **Does anyone have an idea on why?** I had zero issues Saturday night.
- This Morning I tried moving the *Audio Injector* In-between the *HDMI Splitter* and the start of *AV Reciever Run* (point **B**), and every so often I loose audio in the *AV Reciever*

  ### My current thoughts on what to try next...
- I plan to replace the non-shielded parts of the *AV reciever* run. It appears that the *HDMI Pigtales* are compatible with the shielded rj-45 ends but I don't know how much that would help.
- I think I will move the *Audio Inserter* to directly before the *AV Reciever* to hopefully prevent any cut-out issues on the *Projector* run.
- I am running out of ideas on how to resolve this issue if this doen't work. Any ideas of different equipment to completely isolate video signals?
- Im wondering if I need to add another Power conditioner to power the *AV Receiver* , *Café TV Monitor* and other components at that location.

---

My question is. What am I missing.?

Does anybody see what my problem is?

Comment: The first thing I think of is the Audio Inserter has a very small buffer that causes problems during processing; the second thought I have is that perhaps you have an impedance/input expectation problem when plugging the soundboard to the audio inserter. It is not clear to me if you are using the 1/8 jack; if it expects LINE level or "PC speaker level"; and what the soundboard output type is. You may be overdriving (or {other magic}) the audio inserter and it chokes. Also, you should try troubleshooting without the splitter (i.e. only one direct output)

Comment: Note also that impedance mismatching can sound like ground loop/ground lift problems, at least in my experience with using a computer interface for effects pedals for guitar "reamping"

Comment: @Yorik I suspected 'something' like that but didn't know what to do about it.  Until I find a better way, I'm using the tape out (yeah I know) on my (analog) soundboard with an Rca -> 1/8" TSR cable into the *audio Inserter*. Would running through a gate / expanded be a possible solution ?

Comment: The trick is figuring out what the input needs to be, and what your output options are. Your tape-outs are prob -10dbV "consumer line level," the main outs are prob +4dBU. The manual for that inserter device is not clear: it says MP3 device, PC etc. I take that to imply *not* line level. But we still don't know what the expected impedance is. "pc speaker out" impedance is going to be different than mp3-player headphone out impedance.

Comment: But you might simply try lowering by 10dB.

Comment: @Yorik   Yippee..... Do you know of a 'higher end' audio + video combination device? Or is this probably a universal issue for these types of devices. As it stands I will either need to purchase a breakout box to set line level. So it might be just as simple to find a higher end Inserter.